# AudioTrack.play() - can't resolve symbol 'play' (Android Studio)

Tags: android, compiler-errors, android-studio, audiotrack

new Android developer here, following the audio programming tutorial at: http://audioprograming.wordpress.com/2012/10/18/a-simple-synth-in-android-step-by-step-guide-using-the-java-sdk/

I'm running into a problem where my AudioTrack object's call to play() doesn't resolve/compile. I noticed however if I place the method call within a conditional, it resolves just fine. What's going on here? This is all going on within a Thread, btw...

**UPDATE, RESOLVED:
The issue was that the AudioTrack instantiation was taking place within the Thread declaration, instead of within the run() method of the Thread. Moving the code within the run() method resolved the issue. Thanks for the suggestions dudes...**

```
//calculate the size of buffer we need for audiotrack based on sample rate...
int buffsize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(
    sr,  //int 44100
    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

//create an audiotrack object.
AudioTrack myTrack = new AudioTrack(
    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
    sr,
    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
    buffsize,
    AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

//start audio
myTrack.play(); //cannot resolve symbol 'play'
if(1) {
    myTrack.play(); //no problem resolving symbol 'play'
}
```

I've tried cleaning, rebuilding, resynching gradle, and restarting Android Studio...no dice.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated, I realize I'm very possibly missing something basic...thanks!

Compiler output:

```
Error:Error:line (41)<identifier> expected
Error:Error:line (53)illegal start of type
Error:Error:line (53)<identifier> expected
Error:Error:line (61)<identifier> expected
Error:Error:line (62)<identifier> expected
```

Comment: could you please inlude the output of the compiler?

Comment: https://github.com/Audioboo/audioboo-android/blob/master/src/fm/audioboo/application/FLACPlayer.java  see "run()" for sample use in android